# In IPSec what is the definition & purpose of SAD and SPD?

Tags: firewalls, ip, terminology, ipsec

What is a Security Application Database & Security Policy Database? What is their role in processing models for OUTBOUND and INBOUND packets?

[image: PROCESSING MODEL FOR OUTBOUND PACKETS]

[image: PROCESSING MODEL FOR INBOUND PACKETS]

Comment: I've added the images into your post.  Yet, looking at them all they are describing are just a couple of firewall rules.  An SDP may be a database of firewall rules, but it should really be a little more than just that.

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of SAD and SPD in that diagrams?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I am not sure what you mean by a "Security Application Database" I've never heard such a term and upon Googling the term I do *not* get *any* results which appear to reflect your understanding of the abbreviation, however, I digress.

---

`SAD` - Security Association Database

`SDP` - Security Policy Database

`SA` - Security Association

`AH` - Authentication Header

`ESP` - Encapsulating Security Payload

---

**Security Association**

Security Association (SA) is absolutely fundamental to understanding IPSec, in short, an SA is a relationship between two or more entities that describes how those entities will use security to communicate securely. Each IPSec connection can provide encryption, integrity and authenticity. Security Associations are the method that IPSec uses to track its concurrent sessions without this IPSec would fail.

The next section describes what a security association database will look like, it's important to remember that the IPSec peers must match on both sides else the connection will not work. SA parameters are configured by the network admin and then they are stored in the SA database. The following table below describes the parameters that an admin would configure.

[image: SA Parameter Table]

---

**Security Association Database**

A Security Association Database is a table which contains all of the active Security Associations for inbound and outbound traffic, each entry will store the parameters for an individual SA. A SAD will usually store the following entries.

- Security Parameter Index
- Destination Address
- Sequence Number
- Anti-Replay Window
- IP Security Protocol
- Algorithm
- Key
- SA Lifetime
- IPSec

---

**Security Policy Database**

The Security Policy Database contains rules which determine whether or not a packet is subject to IPSec processing. All traffic including inbound and outbound must be processed through this database, the first policy that matches will be used to process the traffic. Each policy has a policy index, the table starts from top-bottom with the top being the most preferred and bottom being the least preferred if however, a packet cannot find a suitable policy then a "NO-POLICY" status will be returned.

Each policy in the table has one or more policy contents and each policy content corresponds to an IPSec protocol either AH or ESP it cannot correspond to both! If a policy requires both then two separate policy contents must be used these policies will be linked using the next content pointer. In it's simplest form the SPD defines a subset of IP traffic and points that traffic to an SA.

---

For further reading on everything, you will ever need to know on IPSec I highly advise looking at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec) and reading the relevant RFCs.